# Hierarchical connection of Twitter subaccounts possible?

Tags: twitter

I would like to have a "me" Twitter account with two subaccounts: me private and me at work. Me at work would again be seperated by different projects. Someone who is interested in me could then either subscribe to the main account to get everything or just to a different subarea. Is that possible natively or using 3rd party applications or do I have to emulate such as system with hashtags?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible either with Twitter or third party apps. Hashtags… possible but it wouldn't look the best to have hashtag on every tweet.

You're better off with multiple Twitter accounts.